# How to do selection in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

When I use base cell (UITabelViewCell) with disclosure indicator and enabled selection, selection occurs by click anywhere in row.
But when I use custom class for cell with UITextField selection occurs only by click outside UITextField. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the `userInteractionEnabled = NO` for textfield.
but if you do this, the textfield won't be selected anymore.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a custom cell which has UITextField embedded inside it, the click on UITextfield will call the UITextField Delegate method not any UITableView delegate method. If you need to select the Custom cell you have to write the code explicitly inside the UITextField delegate method. In order to identify which cell has the UITextField you can use tag property of UITextField which can mention the cell identifier.